# Please how can resolve these issues with uploading my app to google

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-apps, google-play-games

#google app #uploadin app on google play store
Permissions: "App Split Bundle [6]: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO". please how do i resolve this issue on my loan app.
About the Personal Loans policy
Apps that provide personal loans, or have the primary purpose of facilitating access to personal loans (i.e., lead generators or facilitators) are prohibited from accessing sensitive data such as photos and contacts. The following permissions are prohibited:

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
READ_CONTACTS
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
READ_PHONE_NUMBERS
READ_MEDIA_VIDEOS